# Php File with .tpl Extension not Working in Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, opencart

I am doing a project of opencart. In opencart view file have extension .tpl. Opencart is a PHP CMS. But in my netbeans project, .tpl files are not recognizing by editor. even  tag not showing properly.

Comment: Have a look at https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/initial_support_for_smarty_available and https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/how_to_set_up_netbeans1 and http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37379/php-smarty

Comment: @Poria Thank you for reply. but problem is netbeans not recognizing file extension as php.

Comment: But your question says "But in my netbeans project, .tpl files are not working"

Comment: @Poria I am sorry, i could not express properly.

Comment: What I understand is .tpl not working with netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

```
Netbeans
    tools
     options
      Miscellaneous
        Files
```

Now find the row `file extension` select `tpl` . Then most important to Choose the `Associated File Type (MIME)` as `text/x-php5`. After save this, restart netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved by going to NetBeans > options> Miscellaneous > Files. In the row File Extension select tpl. Choose the Associated File Type (MIME) as text/x-php5 and click Apply. then restart Netbeans

Answer (score 1):

```
-You can do this if you follow these steps:    
 1.Open Tools and Select Options.<br>
 2.Select Miscellaneous tab.<br>
 3.Select Files sub-tab thing.<br>
 4.Click on New file extension and enter tpl.<br>
 5.Select the mime type.<br>
 6.Click OK. Done!<br>
 7.(Restart of Netbeans may be required to see the actual changes)
```